# React Custom Hook not triggering DOM updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

Here's a sandbox reproducing my issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ymmyr3o70x?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1

For reasons I can't understand, when I add product via the form, the product list is only updated once, then never again.

I'm using a custom hook (`useObservable`) combined with RxJS to manage state. If you check the console logs, the `ReplaySubject` *does* emit the expected values. But the `useObservable` hook is not triggering an update of the DOM.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your addProduct function mutates the old state instead of creating a new one. Yes, you have the observable emit the state again, but since its the same object as before, calling setValue has no effect and so react does not rerender.

The solution to this is to make the state immutable. For example:

```
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";

let products = {};

export const products$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

export const addProduct = product => {
  products = {...products, [product]: product};
  products$.next(products);
};
```

Comment: Of course! React state 101. For some reason it didn't occur to me when using hooks. I'm surprised they don't remind users about this in the docs, or throw up a warning in the console. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks